# creating a static vb.net "app" that consist of a single picture

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, properties, bitmap, locking

I need to create a vb.net program that consists of a unmovable, always on top bitmap, with no menu bar or anything, and does not show up in the task bar as program.
It needs to always start in the same place.

Essentially I need to mask a part of the screen by using a bitmap that blends into the scenery.

I am not sure which properties I need to tweak to achieve all of this.

Comment: Hmm, what you are really asking for: "how do I stop the user from killing this program, even though it annoys the hell out of them?"  You can't.

Comment: haha, its actually to block some branding for a presentation to client. The branding is going to change anyways, but i did not want it to distract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to try changing the properties until you get the right result, but the below is probably sort of what you're looking for.

```
StartPosition = Manual
ShowInTaskBar = False
SizeGripStyle = Hide
TopMost = True
ControlBox = False
FormBorderStyle = None
Location = X, Y 'wherever it should be
```